# How to set focus to a control that failed validation from inside the validator function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom validator function as follows:

```
export function numRangeValidator(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    let tempVal;
    try {
        tempVal = typeof (control.value) === 'number' ? +control.value : +control.value.replace(/[pP]/g, '');
    } catch { }
    if (control.value === null || control.value === '' || control.value === undefined || !control.value) {
        return null;
    }
    if (control.value !== undefined && (isNaN(tempVal) || tempVal < min || tempVal > max)) {
        control.setValue('');
        return { 'numRange': true };
    }
    return null;
};
}
```

as you can see inside, I set the control's value to '' (empty) when it fails validation.
I would also like to set focus to it, how could i inject the native control into there so I could use its `.focus()` method? Any other way that would fit my situation would be good too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this can help you ? https://coryrylan.com/blog/focus-first-invalid-input-with-angular-forms

Comment: thanks, I did something else eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the `blur` event on the input itself and checking if the control status is Invalid, from inside the custom control component and not the custom validator Fn:

in .html:

```
   <input #oinput (blur)="checkValidation()">
```

and in .ts:

```
export class GenericInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
...
@ViewChild('oinput', { static: false }) oinput: ElementRef;
...
constructor(
  @Optional()
  @Self()
  public controlDir: NgControl
} (
  this.controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
  )
...
checkValidation() {
 if (this.controlDir
     && !(this.controlDir.control.valid
     && (this.controlDir.control.touched 
     && !(this.controlDir.control.hasError('required'))))) {
         this.oinput.nativeElement.focus();
 }
}
```